# intercept when user click on expand all grouping ui grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I use angularJS and ui-grid table .
I want create variable that change when user click on toggle for expand all grouping.
how to intercept when the user click on toggle for expand all grouping . thank's

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gridApi.grouping.on.groupingChanged(scope,function(col){})
```

Refer: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.grouping.api:PublicApi